# Using Stack and then Flexible Positioner in Flutter for Layout?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Having a really difficult time trying to figure out how to add some content under a Stack with an image and header. I created a unique header that overlays an image and a title. I used Stack to do this. I then have a bunch of content that was originally meant to be a flexible widget. Once I wrapped everything in Stack for the header, I can't seem to fix the rest of the content. Everything I have under flexible was the original content which now is all pushed to the top of the page because of Stack. Flutter doesn't seem to allow two layouts, so I can't stack two items and then keep the rest as flexible and lay it out using the rest of the space. I can't figure out how to fix this and it currently just provides errors when run. Everything I try errors out. I've tried wrapping the content under Flexible in a container and assigning a bottom centered position but that also doesn't work... Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: 
      new Stack(children: <Widget>[
        _buildIamge(),
        _buildTopHeader(),
        new Flexible(
            child: new ListView.builder(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
          itemCount: _messages.length,
        )),
        new Divider(height: 1.0),
        new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
          child: _buildTextComposer(),
        ),
      ]),
    );
```

UPDATE:
I have included an image of a page with the header as well as an image of the page that I'm attempting to put the header on, which is the section with the chat input screen:

[App with Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c51cE.png)
[Chat input screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7z8V.png)

Comment: Can you show your design? I think you use Stack in a wrong way.

Comment: Thanks, I've included images of the design in an update to the original question. I used stack to make the header in the "App with Header" section, but the Stack messes with the chat input screen in the second image. If you have a suggestion on how to lay it out, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: So when you add the one Flexible widget, it will cover your header, right? If it is, I think you should put image and top header widget code under Flexible in Stack, but it maybe cover your Flexible widget.

Comment: Despite of using Image and Top Header, you can try ClipPath widget, it can draw as your header background and then using Positioned widget to display header in every where you want in Stack

Comment: Thanks. Had previously tried both of those ideas. I used ClipPath originally but it still sends the textbook up to the top of the page. I also tried moving the image and header under flexible, but the best I can do is then list the header image, then the text in a new section of the app, and then the text input and I no longer have any way to overlap the header and title.

Comment: This is how i think (from under to top): Everything in chat page -> Background header with Clippath -> Tittle with Positioned widget.

Comment: Yup those things you mentioned aren't the issue, it's doing that and then trying to keep the ListView.builder content and below in place at the bottom of the app for the chat function.